# Object creation with interface

Tags: c#

In `C#` we can inherit multiple interfaces. In such scenario if an object is created will it just hide the properties or methods or will the compiler avoids creation and memory allocation to those from other interface? For example, I have two interfaces and a class like below

```
    interface IExample1
    {
        void E1Test1();
        void E1Test2();
    }

    interface IExample2
    {
        void E2Test1();
        void E2Test2();
    }

    class Example : IExample1, IExample2
    {
        public void E1Test1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void E1Test2()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void E2Test1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void E2Test2()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

When I create objects like,

```
IExample1 IE1 = new Example();
IExample2 IE2 = new Example();
```

Will the compiler creates the complete object for both interfaces including all methods and hide it for one which don't have access? or it just creates with the methods which are available for a particular interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you instantiate a class using its constructor (which is after using `new ...`) there´s *always* a complete instance of that clas in memory. There´s no such thing as an instance of an interface.

An interface on the other side is just some kind of a *view* upon that instance. So in your example you have four methods that *all exist* on your instance. However you may or may not access those methods from a *reference* of either type `IExample1` or `IExample2`. E.g. you cannot `E2Test1` on a *reference* of type `IExample1`, although the underlying *instance* does have this method:

```
IExample1 i1 = new Example();
```

Now calling `i1.E1Test1()` will compile just fine, while `i1.E2Test1()` will not, as that method is defined on another interface. However you can simply cast the *instance* which is *referenced* by `i1` to the other interface and access that member this way:

```
IExample i2 = (IExample2) i1;
i2.E2Test1();
```

EDIT as of TimSchmelters comment: If your `Example`-class would implement only `IExample1` and not the other interface casting to that one would surely fail and produce an `InvalidCastException` at runtime. So in that case instances of `Example`-class will only have the members defined on `IExample1`, not on `IExample2`. Casting to the latter makes no sense then.

Comment: Is it same thing happens in case if we use base class? I mean base class object contains child class methods but just can't access them? Can you add it in this answer, I don't want to write another quest for that :)

Comment: @Bharadwaj Yeap, that is comparable in case your base-class-instance actually *is* an instance of your child-class, which is when having `MyBaseClass b = new MyChildClass()`. If you´d creating an instance of the base-class however, how should it know anything about the child-one: `MyBaseClass b = new MyBaseClass()`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, I was referring to the first scenario, second one I know it won't work in that way :)

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an `Example` object on the heap. It has everything that an `Example` has. For instance you can do this.

```
IExample1 IE1 = new Example();
IExample2 IE2 = new Example();
IExample2 casted = (IExample1)IE1;
```

You can also debug and see that `IE1` and `IE2` are in fact `Example` instances.

Answer (score 2):

The methods belong to an instance of a class. That instance is the object.
You can only create a new instance from a concrete type(like a class for example).
You can not create a new instance from an abstract type(Abstract class or Interface).

Thus the conclusion, when you create with new (), you will have all methods in the new instance.

Further:
Your new object(as in your example) can be seen in 3 ways:

1. Directly through the type(Example)
2. Though an interface(IExample1)
3. Through the other interface(IExample2)

  Case 1) You see everything that is declared on the class(lets suppose everything is public :) )

  Case 2) Even though you create new Example(), if the runtime type is IExample1 you will see only what is declared in this interface

  Case 3) Even though you create new Example(), if the runtime type is IExample2 you will see only what is declared in this interface

Conclusion: The object you created is the same one(new Example()) but only the way you look at it changes.

Tip: read about implicit and explicit interface implementation